# In Java, how to delete everything after .com or .net

Tags: java, domain-name

I am trying to get just the domain name (http://www.example.com) out of log files that looks like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl
http://l.macys.com/simi-valley-ca?cm_mmc=macys_     
https://www.google.co.in/       
https://www.google.ca/
```

I want just

```
http://maps.google.com/   
http://l.macys.com/    
https://www.google.co.in/   
https://www.google.ca/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

```
URL url = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl");
System.out.println(url.getProtocol()+"://"+url.getHost());
```

Output

```
http://maps.google.com
```

Comment: Since the `reg-ex` answer was deleted, let me still bring it up. 

Isn't a `reg-ex` solution hairy due to its complexity (unless I'm just a reg-ex fish), plus it grows as `org`, `edu`, etc. get added?

Comment: So how could I do this using regex?

Comment: @cevallos.valtira One of now deleted answers contained this code which would work for you `String truncated = orig.replaceAll("(?<=[.](com|net)).*$", "");`, but using regex in situation where Java gives you tools designed for such address manipulation seems like overkill which was probably the reason why author decided to remove his answer.

Comment: Is there a ways to only get google instead of maps.google.com or www.google.com? Thanks

Comment: @cevallos.valtira I am not sure if this is possible with just URL class. You should probably create new question about it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to handle it yourself, then a full proof way is following:

```
URL url = new URL("http://l.macys.com/simi-valley-ca?cm_mmc=macys_");
    System.out.println(url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost() + ((url.getPort()==-1)?"" : ":" + url.getPort()) + "/" );
```

You can skip url.getPort if you are sure that there will never be a port type url!!

Cheers